# Bootstrap seems to be messing with my navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

In my view template, I am using bootstrap but am adding my own nav bar through css. But the items won't align to the center. 
When I take bootstrap out, they align perfectly. It's really frustrating me. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

### This is my pug template

```
html
  head
    title Articles
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css")
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
  nav.top
    ul
      li 
        a(href='/') HomePage
      if user
        li 
          a(href='/article/add') Add Article
        li 
          a(href ='/users/logout') Logout         
      else
        li 
          a(href ='/users/register') Register
        li 
          a(href='/users/login') Login
  -------------------------------
```

Css

```
.top{
  display : flex;
  background : white;
  align-items : center;
}
.top ul li {
  display : inline;
}
```

Comment: please give the HTML output

Comment: Just so, when you want to over-write CSS property from the one given by Bootstrap, you should always use the inline style sheets i.e. using the CSS directly in HTML elements. Try it, you will be able to overwrite Bootstrap.

Comment: Don't forget that `body` tag